# COMO ARREGLAR 'Failed to parse input string" EN BIGQUERY

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

Estoy tratando de importar datos a una tabla de bigquery desde google cloud storage pero me sale el mensaje: Error while reading data, error message: Could not parse '13/01/23' as DATE for field FECHA_GENERACION (position 28) starting at location 5092480 with message 'Failed to parse input string "13/01/23"'

no se porque sale eso, ni como arreglarlo, help